# Can't seem to get the latest version of H2O to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, h2o

I'm learning how to use h2o but I can't seem to get the latest version to work in Jupyter Notebooks. I can manage to get it running with a very old version though (about 1 year and a few months old). I keep getting stuck when I try to initialise it

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
```

I found there were several versions of h2o that I could download online. Here's what I tried:

I had first downloaded h2o from here (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/h2o) but it could not find the module when I tried importing it over in Jupyter (I installed the package and opened up Jupyter with the same environment [Python 3.6]). This was fixed when I downloaded the additional h2o-py package (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/h2o-py). I could run H2O with these two packages installed, its just that its a pretty old version (3.18.0.2).

Deleting the h2o and leaving only the h2o-py gives me this error:

> H2OStartupError: Cannot start local server: h2o.jar not found.

I also tried getting the latest version from the h2o website (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html) - I am assuming this is the one. I followed the downloading instructions for both pip and conda but neither worked. 
I kept getting the H2O Connection Error and CalledProcess Error when I tried to initialise h2o.

> H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://localhost:54321 after 5 retries
>
> CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/java', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

I tried this in combination with h2o-py, h2o and h2o together (latest one from the website), and just the h2o package alone but nothing is working. So far, the only thing that I got working was the h2o in combination with h2o-py, both of which are the older versions of h2o.

Is there something that I'm missing?

=======================================================================

**TL;DR**

With packages:

1) h2o and h2o-py - *works, but is an older version*

2) h2o only - *cannot find module when importing*

3) h2o-py only - *H2OStartupError: h2o.jar not found*

4) h2o (latest version) and others (h2o (old version) or h2o-py)- *Connection Error when initialising*

5) all three packages together - *Cannot find module when importing*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "java -version" command not working is definitely something you need to resolve.

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/java', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

H2O-3 uses Java underneath the hood to do it's work.  I recommend installing Java 8 on your host.

Start debugging this by running `java -version` by hand in a terminal and see if that helps pinpoint the problem.  Chances are you just need to install java itself.

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been trying to figure this out for hours yesterday. I had no idea the issue was with my computer having no Java. Using the ```java -version``` helped me realise I did not even have Java installed - after installing Java, H2O is finally working

Answer (score 0):

The [officially recommended](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-on-anaconda-cloud) way to install the conda package is

```
conda install -c h2oai h2o
```

I would start with a fresh environment that doesn't contain the other h2o packages you tried. Note that `h2o-py` is not an official h2o package and it's not recommended to ever use it.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure which package to use or that the h2o-py and the h2o from anaconda was not official. I initially thought it had to do with the combination of packages but from TomKraljevic's answer, it turns out it I was just missing Java. I actually already tried ```conda install -c h2oai h2o``` but kept getting the CalledProcess Error. After getting Java instaled, I could run ```h2o.init()``` using the official h2o package from ```conda install -c h2oai h2o``` without any errors.